# How to build ionic 2 ios app on windows 10?

Tags: ios, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2 and i want to build my app to ios version. What requirements need to install on my windows 10 PC?  Thanks. I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: Buy a macbook first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is by using **[Ionic Cloud Services](https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/)**:

> Ionic Packages makes it easy to build a native binary of your app in
>   the cloud. **Perfect for developers using Windows that want to build iOS
>   apps**.
>
> This lets you:
>
> Send your packaged app to others
>
> **Build your app for platforms not supported by your computer (e.g. iOS builds on Windows)**
>
> Build `.ipa` and `.apk` files that you can submit to app stores

You can check the prerequisites **[here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/#prerequisites)** and the steps required to build, **[here](https://docs.ionic.io/services/package/#building)**.

---

**EDIT**:

You can also take a look at this **[amazing post from Josh Morony](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-ionic-2-applications-for-ios-without-a-mac/)**.

Comment: Np :) I've also added a link to a post from Josh Morony

Comment: can you repost the ionic cloud services link.this link is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can't build it to iOS in Windows. Neither in Linux.
You will need an Mac OS.
Either one running on a real Apple device (iMac, Macbook, Mac Mini), or in an virtual box or you can use a cloud service.

Comment: ahh'  so if i build it on Mac,  what are the requirements needed?

Comment: The most important is XCode. So you must know which version of XCode the Mac OS supports, and which versions os Mc OS each hardware supports. Take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html

Comment: Is xcode a prerequisite in order to build ionic app for ios?

Comment: Yes, the Mac OS must have XCode.